# Keep filtering logic on front end or back

Tags: javascript, database, performance, filtering

First of all, I know there is a similar question asked before, but my needs/queries are different, this I am asking this.

I am building a gift recommender app. At most, the number of gifts the database would contain would be 800 to 1000. After completing a quiz, a filter function would be run on the gifts and the one that matches the questions answered most would be recommended. An option of viewing all gifts would be added too.

I wanted to ask whether it would be a bad idea to load all of the gifts when the quiz is started and then implement the filtering logic on the frontend, or should I add it to the backend?

**PS. Each gift is a simple object with 4 to 5 string/number/Boolean properties.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL DR; Back-end

Downloading ~1000 items just to show few to the user is unnecessary data-usage. Doesn't that much matter on desktop, but on mobile this is way different story. Mobiles are slow, have bad connection - and users expect them to be fast.

Create a simple REST / GraphQl API which takes in quiz responses, does the logic and returns just the items which should be shown to the user.

Comment: In addition to simply unnecessary and a bloat, returning all the data to the client means that anybody can access it. This can expose confidential information and even be potentially *illegal*.

Comment: The thing is, the client may or may not choose the 'Show all gifts section' . In that case, i would have to get all the data anyways... Plus, the database maybe Firestore in firebase, just incase

Comment: @SarmadHadi the typical API would have an option to pass a collection of filters that the backend will apply before returning the data. Requesting all data would be done by *not* passing any filters.

Comment: What I meant was, since 50 percent of the time the user would request all of the data anyways, is it worth using a backend for the remaining 50 percent. Thanks though, I appreciate your answer and understand what you want to concern.

Comment: You should implement pagination to show ~1000 data entries to the user. Nobody will actually look and use that much data at once, no need to download them.